# How to export php div to csv row by row

Tags: php, csv

I would like to know how to export php div tags to csv row by row?
Each div has a few lines in them.
Each /br would be the next line.
I have about 65 div tags that I need to export to a file.

Thank you in advance..

```
<div class="container mt-2">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="demo-content">
              <?php echo "!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>";
                    echo "! Menu Configuration</br>";
                    echo "!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>";
                    echo "menu.panel                    = panelRight</br>";
                    echo "menu.autoLoad                 = logo</br>";
                    echo "!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>";
                    echo "! Fast Menus</br>";
                    echo "!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------</br>";
                 ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="demo-content">
              <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement); echo ($row['id'] == 1) ? "btn".$row['btn'].".width"." "."="." ".$row['btnwidth']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".height"." "."="." ".$row['btnheight']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".x"." "."="." ".$row['btnx']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".y"." "."="." ".$row['btny']."</br>".
                          htmlspecialchars("btn".$row['btn'].".text"." "."="." ".$row['btntext'].$row['btntext1'].$row['btntext2'])."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".icon"." "."="." ".$row['btnicon']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".menu"." "."="." ".$row['btnmenu']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".plu"." "."="." ".$row['btnplu']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".command"." "."="." ".$row['btncommand']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".exitType"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitType']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".exitValue"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitValue']:'';?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9">
              <div class="demo-content">
              <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement); echo ($row['id'] == 2) ? "btn".$row['btn'].".width"." "."="." ".$row['btnwidth']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".height"." "."="." ".$row['btnheight']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".x"." "."="." ".$row['btnx']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".y"." "."="." ".$row['btny']."</br>".
                          htmlspecialchars("btn".$row['btn'].".text"." "."="." ".$row['btntext'].$row['btntext1'].$row['btntext2'])."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".icon"." "."="." ".$row['btnicon']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".menu"." "."="." ".$row['btnmenu']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".plu"." "."="." ".$row['btnplu']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".command"." "."="." ".$row['btncommand']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".exitType"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitType']."</br>".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".exitValue"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitValue']:'';?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at `fputcsv()` and use that where you are currently using `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the help!
I got it working. Here is what I did:

```
<div class="demo-content">
              <?php $fp = fopen('../cof/csv/addons1.csv', 'w');
              fputcsv($fp, array("!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------,
                    ! Menu Configuration,
                    !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------,
                     menu.panel                    = panelRight,
                     menu.autoLoad                 = logo,
                     !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------,
                     ! Fast Menus,
                  !-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"),',',chr(0));
              fclose($fp);
                 ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="demo-content">
              <?php $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($statement);
              $thing = array (($row['id'] == 1) ? "btn".$row['btn'].".width"." "."="." ".$row['btnwidth']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".height"." "."="." ".$row['btnheight']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".x"." "."="." ".$row['btnx']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".y"." "."="." ".$row['btny']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".text"." "."="." ".$row['btntext'].$row['btntext1'].$row['btntext2']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".icon"." "."="." ".$row['btnicon']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".menu"." "."="." ".$row['btnmenu']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".plu"." "."="." ".$row['btnplu']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".command"." "."="." ".$row['btncommand']."\n".
                  "btn".$row['btn'].".exitType"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitType']."\n".
                          "btn".$row['btn'].".exitValue"." "."="." ".$row['btnexitValue']:'');?>
                          <?php 
                          $fp = fopen('../cof/csv/addons1.csv', 'a');
                          fputcsv($fp, $thing,"|",chr(0));
                         fclose($fp);?>
                  </div>
        </div>
```

[Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kifdU.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).